# Distance required for a Red Giant Star to have an apparent magnitude of -13

Tags: science-based, earth-like, earth, stars, habitability

Assume this Red Giant has the properties of Aldebaran (α Tauri in constellation Taurus) with an [absolute visual magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude) of −0.641M. How far would it have to be from Earth in order to possess an [apparent visual magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) of -13m, (appearing as bright as a full moon)?
Would this distance constitute a binary system that would screw up Earth's orbit significantly?

Comment: [Advanced Magnitude Calculator](http://www.1728.org/magntudj.htm)

Comment: Downvoters & Closevoters: please remember that [real world questions are on-topic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609). It's true that no one is obligated to explain their vote, but Silvirs is a new user - so buck up and help a new OP learn the ropes. Thanks!

Comment: @JBH, lack of research is a legitimate reason for downvote, on topic or not.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I get that, but apparent magnitude isn't the most researchable topic for people who haven't had a college-level astronomy class, which I'm assuming based on the Q, and besides... new user without a sole pointing out any deficiencies.

Comment: @JBH: *"Apparent magnitude isn't the most researchable topic":* ... except that Wikipedia has a detailed article with the title [Apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude), complete with history and rules for calculation. This question is just an attempt to avoid the chore of firing up Calculator or LibreOffice Calc or whatever favorite calculation tool.

Comment: You can use a program like Celestia or Universe Sandbox to simulate what various astronomical bodies would look like from your world. Personally, I find visuals more satisfying than simply running the numbers.

Comment: @AlexP If we held people consistently to that concept, half the questions on this site would need downvoting. As I told L.Dutch... new user. On the other hand, your first comment looks like an answer. Why didn't you post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- One step of [magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) represents a change in brightness by factor of 2.5. (Actually, it is a factor of $\sqrt[5]{100} = 2.512$, because the definition is that a difference of 5 magnitudes corresponds with a change of brightness by a factor of 100.)
- Brightness decreases with the square of the distance.
- Absolute magnitude is defined as the apparent magnitude that the object would have at a distance of 10 [parsecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec).
- You want the apparent magnitude to be −13. That is 12.34 steps lower than the absolute magnitude of −0.64, which means that the brightness will be higher by a factor of $2.512^{12.34} = 86{,}346$.
- The square root of 86,346 is 293.8. Since the absolute magnitude is reckoned at a distance of 10 parsecs, the required change in brightness will happen at a distance of 10 / 293.8 = 0.034 parsecs = 0.1 light years = 7019 [astronomical units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit).
- A distance of 0.034 parsecs or 0.1 light years is about one fortieth of the distance between the Sun and [Proxima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri) Centauri; and about half the distance between Proxima and the double [α Centauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri), to which it is gravitationally bound.
- So that yes, if [Aldebaran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldebaran) would be so close to the Sun the two stars *might*, quite likely, be gravitationally bound. On the other hand, the gravitational influence of the nearby very bright Aldebaran on Earth would be very small, much smaller than the gravitational influence of Jupiter. On the third hand, it all depends on how fast the two stars are moving relative to one another; they might as well be just passing by, without being gravitationally bound.